# $\sum_{i=0}^{k} a^i$

Tags: summation

$\sum_{i=0}^{k} a^i= \frac{a^{k+1}-1}{a-1} = \Theta(a^k)$

I suppose this sum is true for $a>1$ but if I have $0<a<1$ what the result would be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prove $\sum_{i=0}^ka^i=\frac{a^{\color{blue}{k}+1}-1}{\color{blue}{a}-1}$, use induction. You needn't assume constraints on $a$, except $a\ne1$. But if $|a|<1$, it may be convenient to change the signs of the numerator & denominator, writing the result as $\frac{1-a^{k+1}}{1-a}$. In terms of $\Theta$ notation, note the small-$a$ case achieves a $O(1)$ result with a $k\to\infty$ limit.

Answer (score 0):

For any $\;1\neq a\in\Bbb C\;$ , it in fact must be

$$\sum_{i=0}^k a^i=\frac{a^{k+1}-1}{a-1} $$

You can easily prove this with say induction on $\;k\;$ ...